# Override Tapestry Grid

Tags: css, grid, alignment, tapestry

I want to extend the tapestry Grid component to be able to get the following behavior:

I want a specific column to have the text aligned to the right, which is no problem with css. However I also want the icons for the table sorting (in the table's header) to be left of the text (not right) in this case.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I also want the icons for the table sorting (in the table's
>   header) to be left of the text (not right) in this case.

I'm basing my answer on this random demo: http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/previews/easycrud/persons

```
.t-data-grid th:nth-child(3) a:last-child {
    float: left
}
.t-data-grid th:nth-child(3) a > img {
    margin: 0 4px 0 0
}
```

You can replace `th:nth-child(3)` with a class if desired, for example `th.lastName`.

`:last-child`/`nth-child` is not supported in IE7/8. If you need to support those browsers, you can instead use `:first-child`, which is supported:

```
.t-data-grid th.lastName a {
    float: left
}
.t-data-grid th.lastName a:first-child {
    float: none
}
.t-data-grid th.lastName a > img {
    margin: 0 4px 0 0
}
```